# Fetch data from database using a 'for loop' with a string value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using a For loop to show a A to Z button list of students and watch to fetch data from the initials.

```
@for ($i = 'A'; $i != 'AA'; $i++) 
<h3>Student's Name Starting with "{{$i}}"</h3>
@endfor
```

I'm using this

```
public function showByName()
{
  $student = Student::find($name);
  $student_by_name = DB::table('student_list')->where('name', 'LIKE', 
  $name.'%')->limit(30)->get();
  return view('pages.student', ['student_by_name' => $student_by_name]);
}
```

Instead of using name I want to fetch a list of student starting with the initials of their name or their full name.

```
Route::get('/student/{name}', 'StudentController@showByName');
```

Comment: What's the problem though ? can't you just do `where('fullname', $sutudent->fullname)`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

Fetch student records by initial name (A, B, C, ect.) ?

If user visit `http://your-website.com/student/A`

Then, the page will show 30 students by letter A:

> Andy Foo
>
> Andry FooBar
>
> Angel Bar

```
public function showByName($initial)
{
   $student_by_name= DB::table('student_list')->where('name', 'REGEXP', '^'.$initial)->limit(30)->get();
   return view('pages.student', ['student_by_name' => $student_by_name]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rem I solved it.

```
public function showByAlphabet($alphabet)
{
    $student_by_alphabet= DB::table('student_list')->where('name', 'LIKE', $alphabet.'%')->get();
    return view('pages.student', ['student_by_alphabet' => $student_by_alphabet])->with($alphabet);
}
```